# Why is the value of array key not getting updated?

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array, dynamic-arrays, array-key

I have an array called `$test_data`, and I want to update a key `['test_duration']`. However, I am unable to do this update. Consider the following array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [test_id] => 1116
            [test_name] => ques stats
            [test_no_questions] => 50
            [test_duration] => 28800
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [test_id] => 1112
            [test_name] => Own Test 1
            [test_no_questions] => 2
            [test_duration] => 7200
        )

)
```

I tried the following, but it didn't work out:

```
foreach ($test_data as $key => $value) {
    $value[$key]['test_duration'] = ConvertTimeStampToTimeFormate($value['test_duration']);
}
```

If I print the array after this manipulation, it's printing the same array as before. What is the problem here?

Comment: RTFM: http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

update $test_data instead of $value

```
foreach ($test_data as $key => $value) {
    $test_data[$key]['test_duration'] = ConvertTimeStampToTimeFormate($value['test_duration']);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to nest a furthermore.

```
foreach ($test_data as $arr)
{
  foreach($arr as $k=>$v)
    {
     $value[$k]['test_duration'] = ConvertTimeStampToTimeFormate($value['test_duration']);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like this,

```
foreach ($test_data as $key => $value) {
                      $test_data[$key]['test_duration'] = ConvertTimeStampToTimeFormate($value['test_duration']);
                    }
```